# Python importing package without file in directory?

Tags: python, init

I have been trying to import a package from a parent directory. It works fine, but I can get an absolute path for one directory that doesn't have a file in it.

The current structure is:

```
Level4/
    Level3_1/
       run.py
    Level3/
        __init__.py 
        test.py 
        Level2/
            __init__.py 
            a.py
            b.py
            Level1/
                  d.py
```

Right now, I can call functions in test.py in a.py by doing from Level2.a import a.

However, I want to be able to call it by from Level3.Level2.a import a because I currently can't call function a from run.py.

Comment: in order to be considered as a Python package, a directory must contain a `__init__.py` file (even if it is empty). Adding such a file in Level4 and Level3_1 could help, because you cannot import python modules from directories, only from packages.